# Duplicate Keyboard Shortcuts in WPF-menus

Tags: wpf, menu, duplicates, shortcut

In a WPF-Menu I want to use identical shortcuts in the toplevel-menu and a submenu:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="_File" />
    <MenuItem Header="E_xtra">
        <MenuItem Header="_Format">
        <MenuItem Header="_Organize">
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

In WinForms-menus, if you enter <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, in the dropping submenu you can reach the "Format"-item by entering <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.
In WPF, if you Enter <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, the "File"-item of the toplevel-menu is selected.

Is there a way to force the program to behave like WinForms and use the submenu-shortcut ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Menu Access Keys in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660761/menu-access-keys-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to let go of <kbd>Alt</kbd>, i do not know of a way to change this behavior (and i for always used access keys that way).